# How do I deploy a maven created webapp to tomcat

Tags: maven, web-applications, deployment, jboss

So I was following http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/jsf-2-0-hello-world-example/ for a simple tutorial on how to use maven and jsf. I created a maven project by running mvn archetype:generate -Dfilter=org.apache:maven-archetype-webapp in my command prompt. Then I continued with the tutorial, I wound up creating all necessary files, but then when I got to the end, I realized I did have a server created. So I created one real quick, but when it came to the point of adding files to the server (from the add or remove dialog box), no projects or files showed up. I am not on my computer where the project is located so I can't copy/paste the .pom file in, but it looks practically exactly like the pom in the tutorial (only difference is groupId, artifact, ect.) No additional plugins, dependencies, or configs.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to deploy the webapp within Eclipse to Tomcat? Or as some sort of automatic/continuous deployment?

Within Eclipse you often need to add the Dynamic Web project and JSF facets to your project so Eclipse recognizes the project as deployment capable. If you are using m2eclipse make sure to install the m2eclipse wtp add on so this is done automatically.

If you want to add auto-deployment to the pom.xml I recommend using the maven cargo plugin: http://cargo.codehaus.org/Maven2+plugin - it supports the major containers.

For tomcat you need to modify the tomcat-users.xml to allow auto-deployment and leave the tomcat-manager application in place. If you have startet tomcat and pointing your browser to `http://localhost:8080/manager/html/list` it should either tell you to login or what to add to that file.
The configured user is then used in the configuration to deploy the war file via the tomcat-manager using the `mvn cargo:deploy` goal. The configuration has to be added to the pom.xml using war as packaging, not to the parent-pom.xml

Comment: I just re-did the whole tutorial and it worked. I must have messed something up the first time, but thought it was a config problem since this was my first maven webapp + a separate deployment to a tomcat server